# iOS - How do I perform an action when the user swipes the screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I want to shift the position of some UILabels when the user swipes the screen--specifically, move them the same distance the user swiped their finger.

How would I go about detecting and implementing this?

Thanks

Comment: To get you started concept wise...  The easiest way is to add a swipe gesture recognizer to your view then implement the gesture recognizer's delegates, or create actions for the gesture recognizer.  You can do this either in code or in your storyboard, the choice of which is up to you and which way you want to learn about gestures.

Comment: @Jenn I don't think a swipe gesture recognizer will tell you how far the swipe was.

Answer (score 0):

Override `touchesBegan:withEvent` and `touchesMoved:withEvent:`. Keep track of the starting location in `touchesBegan:withEvent`. If repeated calls to `touchesDragged` (it is called while the drag is happening) show that you are moving fast enough for the action to be a swipe versus just a drag, use the difference between the starting location and the current touch location to animate changing the UILabels.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using following methods for UIView.

In touchesBegan you should store the position where the user first touches the screen. So you can identify the left or right swipe when touches ends.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    self.startPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
}
```

Record the final position on touchesEnded method. By comparing this two positions you can determine the direction of movement.

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject]; 
    CGPoint endPosition = [touch locationInView:self];

    if (startPoint.x < endPoint.x) {
        // Right swipe
    } else {
        // Left swipe
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.